# Fujitsu old computer

Tags: fujitsu-siemens

I have Fujitsu Siemens Intel(R) T2080 1.73GHz 1.00 GB (894 MB usable) 32-bit Operating System in my laptop. What is the best Ubuntu for this System ?. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended for old computers to use lite user interface such as XFCE.

I recommend Xubuntu and I would go for that version 14.04 as it is a Long Term Support version till 2019.

You will need to install  " Xubuntu restricted extras " in order to be able to run flash and MPs on your laptop and some other media files.

Comment: `Xubuntu` and `Lubuntu` are both Operating Systems which can be used.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: Also, if the user is experienced, they can choose the server edition and build a gui on top of it. Removes a lot of unnecessary things that will never be used and will just consume resources.

Comment: You are right there , but that needs a lot of knowledge that might not be existing in many of the folks who request and seek help. Thanks for your comment mate.